# Find element within table cell

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, cell

I'm trying to access hidden fields which are embedded in table cells:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <image .../>
        <a .../>
        <input type="hidden" id="hfID" Value="myValue" />
    </td>
</tr>
//there are more TR's like this inside the table
```

Javascript:

```
var elemTable = document.getElementById(sTable); 

for (var i = 0, row; row = elemTable.rows[i]; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    } 
}
```

I know that I can access the cell with "col", but I don't know how to access that one hidden field inside that cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
  document.getElementById('hfID');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<script>
    var elemTable = document.getElementById('hfID'); 
alert(elemTable);

</script>
<input type="hidden" id="hfID" Value="myValue" />
```